# Choosing the right classes (from nouns) to build my project

Tags: java, class

The thing is that I've been coding the following exercise and I wanted to ask you something about it:

---

Develop a system that meets the following requirements:

Create a test generator reminding the following functional requirements:

- There are two types of questions: open and multiple choice. The first ones are textual questions that students must develop to respond. The latter are textual questions that have options for students to choose 1. Each question belongs to a topic and each topic is identified by a code and a description.
- An exam has N questions and every question has an answer (entered by the student). It is important to identify the student that takes the test and the examiner (the person who assembled the exam).
- In order to generate the test, the examiner must indicate the amount of questions you want for each topic. The questions are selected at random from a database of questions. The correction is made in two parts: automatic correction in multiple choice and manual correction in the open questions.
- Generated tests should persist and it must be able to create a copy of each exam for each student. The student completes the test, then get the correction automatically, awaiting for manual correction by the examiner. Finally, to complete the correction, the examiner corrects the open questions.
- Reports: List of exams and resolutions showing the questions and answers of each exam for each student along with it's note.

---

I've already coded my program, but the thing is that I have some doubts about choosing the right classes to build my project, because sometimes I can't tell if all nouns from the requirements should be classes or not, or if it just depends on the scope of the system... Reading a couple of books, I've found that we have to select only nouns that have a meaning, and for that reason we usually omit some of them.

The classes I have are the following:

```
public class Student {

    private String name;

    // methods

}

public class Exam { // the examiners create the exams

    private int id;
    private Examiner examiner;
    private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
    private List<Test> tests = new ArrayList<Test>();

    private Map<Topic, Integer> quantityChosenPerTopic = new HashMap<Topic, Integer>();
    private Map<Topic, List<Question>> questionsByTopicDisordered;

    // methods

}

public class Examiner {

    private String name;

    // methods

}

public abstract class Question {

    private Topic topic;
    private String text;

    // methods

}

public class OpenQuestion extends Question {

    // methods

}

public class MultipleChoiceQuestion extends Question {

    private List<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String correct;

    // methods

}

public class Test { // the students take the tests

    private int number;
    private Student student;
    private float mark = -1;
    private Map<Question, String> answers = new HashMap<Question, String>();

    private Map<Question, Boolean> correction = new HashMap<Question, Boolean>();

    // methods

}

public class Topic {

    private int code;
    private String description;

    // methods

}
```

In the previous version of the system, I also had these classes:

```
public class Option {

    private String option;

    // methods

}

public abstract class Answer {

    // methods

}

public class OpenAnswer extends Answer {

    private String text;

    // methods

}

public class MultipleChoiceAnswer extends Answer {

    private Option option;

    // methods

}
```

A person who helped me with this decided to take out those last classes: Option, Answer, OpenAnswer and MultipleChoiceAnswer. The reason he gave me was that it has not much sense to have them in the program because they just handle one variable and he recommended me to use them as that. And other person told me that it's important that the code works and it should be understandable by other people, plus it's not recommended to have many little classes that don't have almost nothing or very big classes with lots of code. That's why I wanted to ask you that. Thanks.

Comment: There are two common approaches to handling polymorphism over data - type hierarchies (e.g. classes, interfaces, subtypes) and algebraic data-types (e.g. pattern matching, switch statements). Java *generally works best with type hierarchies with specialized classes*. For similar reading, search for "java visitor pattern" (a visitor pattern isn't necessarily used here, but it is often used orthogonally to ADTs and can show the differences). Also, don't worry that a class only "has one variable" - if it represents a different specialization, that's usually enough justification.

Comment: (Also, *prefer interfaces for type hierarchies*. Abstract classes are useful for sharing implementation, but interfaces are ultimately more flexible.)

Answer (score 0):

I would code it so that the resulting classes will have some behaviour, if a class consists only of information then it's better to view it as a data structure.

So, in my opinion, I would not create classes adding properties first, but their methods, by doing so you automatically exclude data structures from classes.

You said

> Reading a couple of books, I've found that we have to select only nouns that have a meaning, and for that reason we usually omit some of them

...in my opinion a meaning reflect actions that could be carried out by a class, methods.